# User registration in MongooseIM server

Tags: pidgin, mongoose-im

I have tried to register an account from Pidgin chat client to Mongoose Instant Messaging server. But, I would like to confirm whether the account has been registered successfully in the server ? Could any one please let me know, where I can see all the registered account details in the Mongoose Instant Messaging server ?

Comment: if you are using mysql or postgres,you can view the table users.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me how to delete an existing user from mongooseim server and how to connect a user using terminal. I am able to create users but can't able to login via any xmpp client like Adium.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the registered users in your server with the command

```
mongooseimctl registered_users localhost
```

Assuming you have access to the server where mongooseim is installed.